# Can Hibernate support change in DB Objects related to new columns with code changes

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, hibernate-mapping

Can someone guide me if I can use Hibernate for CRUD operations but the main design requirement is to make sure that newly added columns to tables are dynamically available for Updates or insert with out making code changes. This is for a Library Management functionality

Is this feasible, previously I made such application using plain JDBC where table information was retrieved from system tables. Not sure if that can be done using Hibernate.

Any suggestions or approach is welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

No. You need to have the appropriate fields in your entities. You can still use raw JDBC for that though.

But since you will be deploying new code anyway, you'd better add the corresponding fields. It is always best to have your entities correspond perfectly to the database.